# Problem with hiding DIV from website using GreaseMonkey

Tags: html, greasemonkey-4

There's one site, where without ads you cannot view the content.
I tried Anti-Ad Blocker already, but scripts made all links unusable.

I tried writing Greasemonkey script to hide those few ads by hand, but so far it doesn't work (and I have no idea why).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Hide annoying shinden ads
// @include  https://shinden.pl/*
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==



var div = document.getElementById("banner-outer");
if (div) {
    div.style.display = "none";
}
```

---

And element I want to delete:

```
<div id="banner-inner" style="transform: matrix(0.99999, 0.00087, -0.00087, 0.99999, 0, 0);">
            ...
        </div>
```

Also sometimes different div appears out of random, that blocks whole site:

```
<div style="position: fixed; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; inset: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); z-index: 300000;"></div>
```

I don't know how to remove it, as thus it doesn't have an ID.

P.S Site is as follows: https://shinden.pl/

Comment: Site is a secret ? Maybe you can use existing -inner ID and then DOM relatives like parentElement, firstChild, nextSibling, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Div from webpage using code below.

If the random Div is creating inside the "banner-inner Div" then above solution helps creating such Divs.

If it is creating outside then have to find the Div by available properties like width, hieght , z-index along with grand parent of the Div(which has ID) to pinpoint and delete the created div.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     RemoveDiv
// @version  1.0
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var toBeRemoved = document.getElementById('banner-inner');
if (toBeRemoved) {
    toBeRemoved.parentNode.removeChild(toBeRemoved);
}
```